# PHPEXCEL выдает ошибку на функцию sum

Tags: php, phpexcel

В ячейку вставляю функцию sum, таким образом: $page->setCellValue("E15", "=СУММ(E5:E14)");
Выдает ошибку: PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\ivc\test\php\PHPExcel-1.8\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\Excel2007\Worksheet.php on line 1117

На 1117 идет:

```html
case 'f':            // Formula
                        $attributes = $pCell->getFormulaAttributes();
                        if ($attributes['t'] == 'array') {
                            $objWriter->startElement('f');
                            $objWriter->writeAttribute('t', 'array');
                            $objWriter->writeAttribute('ref', $pCellAddress);
                            $objWriter->writeAttribute('aca', '1');
                            $objWriter->writeAttribute('ca', '1');
                            $objWriter->text(substr($cellValue, 1));
                            $objWriter->endElement();
                        } else {
                            $objWriter->writeElement('f', substr($cellValue, 1));
                        }
                        if ($this->getParentWriter()->getOffice2003Compatibility() === false) {
                            if ($this->getParentWriter()->getPreCalculateFormulas()) {
//                                $calculatedValue = $pCell->getCalculatedValue();
                                if (!is_array($calculatedValue) && substr($calculatedValue, 0, 1) != '#') {
                                    $objWriter->writeElement('v', PHPExcel_Shared_String::FormatNumber($calculatedValue));
                                } else {
                                    $objWriter->writeElement('v', '0');
                                }
                            } else {
                                $objWriter->writeElement('v', '0');
                            }
                        }
                        break;
```

Comment: А можете добавить в вопрос полный стек с ошибкой (кнопка [edit])?

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что библиотека пытается устанавливать `cell.Formula`, а ни разу не `cell.FormulaLocal`...

Comment: Предполагаю что по исходникам библиотеки ошибка произошла в `$attributes = $pCell->getFormulaAttributes();` + `if ($attributes['t'] == 'array') {`, в условии, т.к. в `$attributes` был null. PHPExcel уже давно не поддерживается, поэтому, когда для одной подработки работал с PHPExcel, пришлось руками исправлять баги. Я бы предложил использовать другую библиотеку, либо исправить эту ошибку самостоятельно :)

Comment: $objWriter->text(substr($cellValue:$cellValue)); Может в условии дописать?

Comment: PHPExcel умер, советую использовать PhpSpreadsheet

Comment: мне одно интересно, с какого перепугу пхпэксель должен понимать корявого уродца "СУММ" если чуть раньше в вопросе написано нормальное название функции

Comment: Так без разницы , одна и та же ошибка.

Comment: $page->setCellValue('E15', '=SUM(E4:E15)'); так же выдают туже ошибку

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос закрыт. Просто удалил условие и заработало, удалил это :

```html
if ($attributes['t'] == 'array') {
                            $objWriter->startElement('f');
                            $objWriter->writeAttribute('t', 'array');
                            $objWriter->writeAttribute('ref', $pCellAddress);
                            $objWriter->writeAttribute('aca', '1');
                            $objWriter->writeAttribute('ca', '1');
                            $objWriter->text(substr($cellValue, 1));
                            $objWriter->endElement();
                        } else {
                            $objWriter->writeElement('f', substr($cellValue, 1));
                        }
```